# kohana with data tables

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, database-table

I want to use Data Tables in Kohana 3.0, but in all examples they core PHP code and normal queries. Is there any tutorial or example on how to use Kohana  with data tables ??

Example:

```
 $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(",",$aColumns))."FROM $sTable $sWhere $sOrder $sLimit";
```

How to write this type of queries in Kohana like `DB::select(...)`? Give some good suggestions about writing queries in Kohana.

Comment: What do you mean with "data tables"? And why do you use so outdated version of framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `where_open()` and `where_close()`  method for where conditions..

For Example

```
$query = DB::select()
       ->from('table')
       ->where_open()
       ->where('column1', '=', 1)
       ->or_where('column2', '=', 2)
       ->where_close();
```

would produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 = 1 OR column2 = 2);
```

You can find more about kohana sql select query builder on url given below.

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder

I hope it will be helpful for you,

thanks